# Exhaust fan from ceiling is dropping water, but the roof might show a bigger problem

Tags: roof, attic, exhaust-fan, water-damage, leaking

I'm living in the Northeast coasts, and I saw my exhaust fan from the ceiling is dropping water this morning. So this afternoon, I access my attic to see the inner roof and see a potentially bigger problem.

Please see the image below. My house roof shape is a "triangle". I saws there is black tape along the edges. But somewhere along the edge, I can see open-air, where I marked it with a red circle. Also, I saw a few drops of water in the pink diamond area, as marked on the picture.

What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: call a roofing company

Comment: Your ridge flashing has been damaged or deteriorated, as suggested, you need a roofer.

Comment: can you see it from the outside or safely get on the roof?  It looks like your ridge vent is gone in that section.

Comment: It was very windy where I am in the NE US, so blowing the cap shingles off of the ridge vent is believable.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to the collective in the comments: you need a roofer.

Given NE weather lately, they’re busy, so you might just engage one to temporarily tarp the area. That’ll give you breathing room to get 3 quotes and check references.